# GeoServer in Tomcat doesn't get update shapefiles from PostGis

Tags: gis, geospatial, postgis, shapefile, geoserver

I have two GeoServers running in the same machine Ubuntu Server 9.04. GeoServer V2.0.1 is running with Jetty and another GeoServer V2.0.0 is Tomcat. Both of them are using the same PostGis datastore.

When I post new shapefile via Rest api to GeoServer in Jetty, The GeoServer in Tomcat doesn't get update shapefile from PostGis.

It may have the way to tell GeoServer in Tomcat in configuration or service to reload shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue just reinstall GeoServer to the newer version 2.0.1 is Tomcat.
It seems GeoServer V2.0.0 has the bug.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by posting a shapefile to geoserver. I ask because you in the next line expects postgis to be updated with this new data.

My guess is that in your jetty-installation you are not pointing to the postgis database, but directly to the shapefile. In the tomcat-installation you are pointing to the postgis table that you earlier has loaded to the database.

I am not familiar with what it means to load a shapefile via REST api to geoserver, but if you are supposed to get the new data out of PostGIS this process have to load the data into postgis, probably dropping the old table and creating this new table.

Again, my guess is that that is not happening, that you are just uploading the shapefile to the server, where the jetty-installation reads from the shape file.

Just a guess!

HTH
Nicklas

Comment: I use poster in FireFox to post Shapefile via rest API. Both Geoserver are pointing to the same PostGis datastore.